# Is it possible for fully connected layers to learn square/cube operations?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

Is there any structure for fully connected layers that could learn square/cube operations?
As far as I known, fully connected layers could learn linear representation well. But for specific no-linear representation it remains a mystery.

`2^2 = 4
2^3 = 8`

Comment: This question is a bit of mystery to me... Why do you need neural networks to learn cubic or quadratic function?

Comment: @JanKukacka Because I want to interpret a model, I think this model may has implemented square operation. But this model is a bit complex.

Comment: Are you asking if a neural network with linear activations can learn the square function, or something else?